# pointer arithmetic in C for getting a string

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I want to get the elements of an array of characters, but no success at all, the problem is that I only get the first and last element and nothing more, my code is:

```
void getcharacters(char *cad)
{
 int l;
 int *i;
 l=strlen(cad);
 for (i=&cad[0];i<&cad[l];i++){
     printf("%c\n",*cad);
 }
}
```

any help?
Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't `i` be declared as `char *i`?

Comment: Also, why print *cad? It never changes from the first character.

Comment: Perhaps you intended to print `*i` instead of `*cad`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same character (`*cad` or `cad[0]`) for all printf's. What you need is to use the index to get the next char in each iteration. Also i needs to be a pointer to char:

```
void getcharacters(char *cad)
{
 int l;
 char *i;
 l=strlen(cad);
 for (i=&cad[0];i<&cad[l];i++){
     printf("%c\n", *i );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The size of an `int` can be as big as 4 x the size of a `char`, so when you do `i++` you are actually skipping 3 chars.

Also, you print out `*cad` instead of `*i`.

To fix change `i` to `char*` and print `*i` instead of `*cad`

Comment: "`int` can be as big as 4 `char`s" lol, I would say `char` is not guaranteed to be the same size of `int` (and in most cases they will never be)

Comment: @AlvinWong  typically sizeof(int) == 4 while sizeof(char) == 1 i believe

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you iterate from first character to the last one and accessing them as array index

```
int i;
int l=strlen(cad);
for (i=0;i<l;i++)
{
  printf("%c\n",cad[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have told you why it plain doesn't work, I'm wonder why you're not just iterating until the null terminator?

```
void getcharacters(char *cad)
{
 char *i;
 for (i = cad; *i; i++) {
     printf("%c\n",*i);
 }
}
```

Comment: `i` should be a `*char` instead of `*int`